# Amplitude of a wave: will it be an overlap of two waves or is there another reason?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, reflection, computational-physics

For a wave with initial conditions and with a velocity = 1.00 m / s the following graph was obtained:

[image]
The spatial domain is [0; 50] m and the time domain is [0, 50] s. The wave reaches the boundary and is reflected (the reflected wave has negative amplitude) and have maximum amplitudes. I do not understand why the wave at time t = 40 s does not have maximum amplitude. I already thought that this could be due to the overlap of the wave that goes in the positive direction with the reflected wave, but if it were, the wave would have half of the maximum amplitude and in this case it has less than half of the amplitude. Could one explain why the wave does not have maximum amplitude for t = 40 s?

Comment: Could you provide more background information for your system? (e.g. the Hamiltonian and boundary conditions ...etc)

Comment: @K_inverse I haven't the hamiltonian but I have the boundary conditions: $u(x,0)=exp(x-10)^2$ and $u(x,-\Delta t)=exp(x-v\Delta t-10)^2$

Comment: @K_inverse v=1,00 m/s and $\Delta t=0,1$ s

Comment: Have you found an answer? Or can you copy and paste it on Matter Modeling SE (please)?